# Renaming files and directories

Tags: scripts, files, directory, rename, batch

I have a ton of file films and directories which naming structure is:
*Name of the film (Author, year)*
or
*Name of the film (Author, year) LANG*

I intend to rename them all (almost three thousands) in this way

*Author - Name of the film - Year - LANG*

or something very similar to this.

My question is: is there a way to do the batch renaming with a simple script?

Thanks a lot in advance, guys.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although you could do this with regex capture groups in the perl-based `rename` tool, my choice for this would probably be `mmv` ex.

```
$ mmv -n '* (*, *) *' '#2 - #1 - #3 - #4'
Name of the film (Author, year) LANG -> Author - Name of the film - year - LANG
```

The cases with and without the `LANG` component are easiest handled separately - for the latter case, you can reduce the command to

```
mmv -n '* (*, *)' '#2 - #1 - #3'
```

A similar thing is possible in `zsh` with the `zmv` contrib module:

```
 % zmv -n '(*) \((*), (*)\) (*)' '$2 - $1 - $3 - $4'
mv -- 'Name of the film (Author, year) LANG' 'Author - Name of the film - year - LANG'
```

Remove the `-n` when you are happy that the transformation is correct (one obvious gotcha is if `Name of the film` ever contains parentheses).

Comment: Many film titles do contain parentheses (some even multiple pairs of parentheses, like "Zeit(en) und Porträt(s)"), so I did some testing. Parentheses in titles break your `mmv` command, but *your `zmv` command still works*. A Perl `rename` (i.e., `file-rename` or `prename`) approach could of course be crafted with extra parentheses in mind, but even if written naively, seems to *usually* work. This is because, in the input, the title appears first, and regex quantifiers are eager by default, so the engine picks up what it can, then backtracks to give up the last parenthesis-enclosed substring.

Answer (score 0):

- 1st solution provided by steeldriver works perfectly. In some cases
  small changes has to be done, since some of the film names has no LANG associated.
- By the way, How can this be done in recursive mode? I haven't find the option in the mmv documentation.

I answer to myself. After some internet digging and some tests I could manage to do change the files contained in folders. The ; is used to indicate the system (without -r) to dive into folders. BUT the ; will become the first variable, so the order will be something like this:

mmv ';* (*, *).*' '#1#3 - #2 (#4).#5'

In this situation #1 correspond to the ; and the rest is part of the name changing.

So, thanks a lot to steeldriver to teach me a new and powerful tool to batch renaming esaly.
And also thanks Elia Kagan for his comment.